# Computing eigenvectors from a transition matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-modeling, python, transition-matrix

I have a 21x21 transition matrix modeling the population of a species, and I'm trying to find the long term population proportions of the states. To do this, I'm using numpy.

I found the dominant eigenvalue to be 1.128+0i, however when I access that eigenvalue's associated right eigenvector (which should give long term population proportions), I'm getting an eigenvector with complex entries.

Can a real eigenvalue have a complex eigenvector? I'm beginning to think my numpy code for calculating these values may be incorrect.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfeqB.png) is the matrix. Blank entries have a value of zero.

Comment: Is it possible to post the matrix?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Are you getting something like: $\lambda =1.127649281886682$ and $v_1 = \{-0.593046+0. i,-0.315548+0. i,-0.223862+0. i,-0.188595+0. i,-0.167246+0. i,-0.148314+0. i,-0.131525+0. i,-0.116637+0. i,-0.077575+0. i,-0.0233898+0. i,-0.446881+0. i,-0.237777+0. i,-0.189774+0. i,-0.159877+0. i,-0.137526+0. i,-0.118299+0. i,-0.0996625+0. i,-0.0839618+0. i,-0.0707345+0. i,-0.0439092+0. i,-0.0311509+0. i\}$

Comment: I wonder if you have some machine precision, rounding or those types of issues. Are you using infinite precision? Can you increase that?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. The eig() function returns the eigenvectors as columns, when I was reading them as the rows. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The eig() function returns the eigenvectors as columns. To access the one I needed, I took the transpose of the evecs array, and then called the desired eigenvector: evecsTrans[i]